# How do I create a fullscreen scrollable gallery in android layout?

Tags: android, layout, gallery, fullscreen, scrollable

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <Gallery
       android:id="@+id/gallery"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:spacing="5dp"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to create fullscreen gallery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set **@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen** to the activity declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml file to gain FullScreen view.

For example:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I have also added   imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(320, 480));
in my Adapter

Comment: will you please tell me where you have added the line  imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(320, 480)); exactly please

Comment: i think he has set this to the images used in Adapter's **getView** method. For more details read [this](http://raivoratsep.com/114/android-gallery-tutorial-working-example/)